# Folder Permissions not Sticking

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, linux-mint, plex

I'd like to think I'm not a linux noob but I am having an issue I can't explain. I hope it something stupid. I have an external drive that I am trying to set up on plex. It was originally formatted `ntfs` but I shrunk the partition and made another `ext4` partition. Plex can't look into the drive and see the folders. I have been trying to change the perms but they aren't sticking. They don't stick if

```
myUser@mint /media/myUser $ ls -lah
total 44K
drwxr-x---+ 6 root   root   4.0K Oct 24 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4.0K Oct 24 10:50 ..
drwx------  1 myUser myUser  20K Oct 14 07:27 DataDisk


myUser@myUserMint /media/myUser $ sudo chmod -R 766 DataDisk/
[sudo] password for myUser: 


myUser@mint /media/myUser $ ls -lah
total 44K
drwxr-x---+ 6 root   root   4.0K Oct 24 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4.0K Oct 24 10:50 ..
drwx------  1 myUser myUser  20K Oct 14 07:27 DataDisk
myUser@mint /media/myUser $
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this just weird?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chmod g+rw,o+rw DataDisk/` ?

Comment: Is `DataDisk/` a mount point for another file system?